# QUERY error: "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows"

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Hoping someone can help me with this one!

I'm pulling data from a large revenue forecast table and summarising it into several individual (neater) tables, to give a Jan to Dec forecast table for each client in the main forecast.

**Output data will consist of:**

CLIENT A

Column A: Project Name

Column B: Revenue Status

Column C: Jan value

Column D onwards: Feb to Dec values

Status of revenue in the original data source (Column C) is either Contracted, Proposed, Identified and To Find.   Client A only has Contracted and To Find revenue, so the array formula that I have built gives an error because it cannot find data for Proposed and Identified.

**Source data**

LINK HERE:
[LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k8pbW4GnRalNDFZ_uIVXZ3-MsymElpvEr2FDqWXq5FM/edit?usp=sharing)

Column G is the project name, Column C is the Revenue Status and Columns L-W is the months January to December.

Here's my formula (shortened for only 2 types of revenue status, there are 4 in total). I should add that I am trying to custom sort the Revenue Status, in order of how secure the forecasted figure is.

```
={QUERY('2019_MRS Data'!A:W,"select G,C,sum(L),sum(M),sum(N),sum(O),sum(P),sum(Q),sum(R),sum(S),sum(T),sum(U),sum(V),sum(W) where (E='"&A2&"') AND C='Contracted'GROUP BY C,G ORDER BY C label sum(L)'',sum(M)'',sum(N)'',sum(O)'',sum(P)'',sum(Q)'',sum(R)'',sum(S)'',sum(T)'',sum(U)'',sum(V)'',sum(W)'' ",1);QUERY('2019_MRS Data'!A:W,"select G,C,sum(L),sum(M),sum(N),sum(O),sum(P),sum(Q),sum(R),sum(S),sum(T),sum(U),sum(V),sum(W) where (E='"&A2&"') AND C='Proposal'GROUP BY C,G ORDER BY C label sum(L)'',sum(M)'',sum(N)'',sum(O)'',sum(P)'',sum(Q)'',sum(R)'',sum(S)'',sum(T)'',sum(U)'',sum(V)'',sum(W)'' ",1)}
```

Comment: Is there a way that the data can be custom sorted - I'm trying to make sure that the results show in the table in following order: Contracted|Proposal|Anticipated|CIBS|UBS|Missed. When I use the regex query in my linked doc, CIBS shows higher in my results table than Contracted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regex in query like this:

```
=QUERY('2019_MRS Data'!A:W,
 "select G,C,sum(L),sum(M),sum(N),sum(O),sum(P),sum(Q),sum(R),sum(S),sum(T),sum(U),sum(V),sum(W) 
  where E='"&A2&"' 
    and C matches 'Contracted|Proposal|Identified|To Find'
  group by C,G 
  order by C 
  label sum(L)'',sum(M)'',sum(N)'',sum(O)'',sum(P)'',sum(Q)'',sum(R)'',sum(S)'',sum(T)'',sum(U)'',sum(V)'',sum(W)''", 1)
```

[image: 0]

### [ARRAY_LITERAL ERROR explained](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131436/186471)

---

### UPDATE:

```
=QUERY({IFERROR(QUERY('2019_MRS Data'!A:W,
 "select G,C,sum(L),sum(M),sum(N),sum(O),sum(P),sum(Q),sum(R),sum(S),sum(T),sum(U),sum(V),sum(W) 
  where E='"&A2&"' 
    and C matches 'Contracted'
  group by C,G 
  order by C 
  label sum(L)'',sum(M)'',sum(N)'',sum(O)'',sum(P)'',sum(Q)'',sum(R)'',sum(S)'',sum(T)'',sum(U)'',sum(V)'',sum(W)''", 0),
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(QUERY('2019_MRS Data'!A:W,
 "select G,C,sum(L),sum(M),sum(N),sum(O),sum(P),sum(Q),sum(R),sum(S),sum(T),sum(U),sum(V),sum(W) 
  where E='"&A2&"' 
    and C matches 'Proposal'
  group by C,G 
  order by C 
  label sum(L)'',sum(M)'',sum(N)'',sum(O)'',sum(P)'',sum(Q)'',sum(R)'',sum(S)'',sum(T)'',sum(U)'',sum(V)'',sum(W)''", 0),
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(QUERY('2019_MRS Data'!A:W,
 "select G,C,sum(L),sum(M),sum(N),sum(O),sum(P),sum(Q),sum(R),sum(S),sum(T),sum(U),sum(V),sum(W) 
  where E='"&A2&"' 
    and C matches 'Anticipated'
  group by C,G 
  order by C 
  label sum(L)'',sum(M)'',sum(N)'',sum(O)'',sum(P)'',sum(Q)'',sum(R)'',sum(S)'',sum(T)'',sum(U)'',sum(V)'',sum(W)''", 0),
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(QUERY('2019_MRS Data'!A:W,
 "select G,C,sum(L),sum(M),sum(N),sum(O),sum(P),sum(Q),sum(R),sum(S),sum(T),sum(U),sum(V),sum(W) 
  where E='"&A2&"' 
    and C matches 'CIBS'
  group by C,G 
  order by C 
  label sum(L)'',sum(M)'',sum(N)'',sum(O)'',sum(P)'',sum(Q)'',sum(R)'',sum(S)'',sum(T)'',sum(U)'',sum(V)'',sum(W)''", 0),
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(QUERY('2019_MRS Data'!A:W,
 "select G,C,sum(L),sum(M),sum(N),sum(O),sum(P),sum(Q),sum(R),sum(S),sum(T),sum(U),sum(V),sum(W) 
  where E='"&A2&"' 
    and C matches 'UBS'
  group by C,G 
  order by C 
  label sum(L)'',sum(M)'',sum(N)'',sum(O)'',sum(P)'',sum(Q)'',sum(R)'',sum(S)'',sum(T)'',sum(U)'',sum(V)'',sum(W)''", 0), 
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(QUERY('2019_MRS Data'!A:W,
 "select G,C,sum(L),sum(M),sum(N),sum(O),sum(P),sum(Q),sum(R),sum(S),sum(T),sum(U),sum(V),sum(W) 
  where E='"&A2&"' 
    and C matches 'Missed'
  group by C,G 
  order by C 
  label sum(L)'',sum(M)'',sum(N)'',sum(O)'',sum(P)'',sum(Q)'',sum(R)'',sum(S)'',sum(T)'',sum(U)'',sum(V)'',sum(W)''", 0),
 {"","","","","","","","","","","","","",""})}, "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```